# Converting column in pandas to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert a pandas data frame column from string to a datetime type.I am sure I am doing it correctly but am getting an error saying that the format does not match and I can not work out why.
My strings I want to convert look like this

```
Date
2019-02-03 04:09:34 
2019-02-02 14:21:03
2019-02-02 16:54:13 
2019-02-02 17:39:19
2019-02-02 09:13:38
2019-01-05 09:03:24 
2019-02-02 16:50:34 
2019-02-02 16:05:50 
2019-02-02 07:28:10
```

I am trying this on the file containing this data

```
file['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(file['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d :%H:%M:%S')`
```

But repetitively get the error

```
 ValueError: time data ' Date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d :%H:%M:%S' (match)`
```

I have been able to make this work but only for one row not the entire column

```
file['Date1'] = datetime.strptime(file['Date'][1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, Thank you

Comment: Have you tried letting `pandas` infer the format, e.g. `pd.to_datetime(file.Date)`? Note: you seem to have a spurious `:` before `%H` in your format.

Comment: Doesnt work, says it is an unknown string format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your additional `:` before `%:H` in your format string. `pandas` is looking for a colon and can't find it in the data you provide.

Additionally, I tested `pd.to_datetime` without a format string, and it appears to be able to infer the format, so you could do that too.

Comment: I fixed that and it still doesnt work. "time data Date doesnt match format specified

Comment: Is the first row in your DataFrame the string `Date`? If so, you need to remove it.

Comment: hahahaha i had removed the # from the header line. that fixed it thank you so much!